# Firebase storage secure downloads from web

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, firebase-storage

I am creating a web app with Firebase/AngularFire, and one feature is the ability to upload files and documents that contain private information. I only want authorized users of the app to be able to view these documents. Currently I'm storing the Download URL in the database for use within the UI, but this link is publicly shareable with no validation of the user.

My understanding is that access to the gs:// Storage Location goes through the Storage Rules, but I'm not sure how to implement retrieval of the document using this URL in the app.

Does this need to be implemented on the server, like with Cloud Functions? Where somehow the server validates the user, fetches the file and responds with it? I haven't looked into how a user's session is or can be passed to a Cloud Function to be used with the validation piece...Obviously the server's request to storage could be administrative and have access to everything, but it still needs to know and verify who made the request.

Any pointers or examples would be very helpful. It seems like this shouldn't be so difficult to find information about. The documentation seems to skirt over how to implement the gs:// path.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing this *but this link is publicly shareable with no validation of the user*? A very simple [Firebase Rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) would limit access to that node and with a little extra rule, it could be limited to a specific user.

Comment: @Jay But there would be nothing stopping that specific user from taking the "protected" download URL and sharing it to the world on their own.

Comment: @DougStevenson. Not sure I understand... Maybe I don't get the question either. lol. The OP says *I only want authorized users of the app to be able to view these documents* so.... that means that an authorized user should be able to access their own document. If they have access to their document, they could download it and email it to all of their friends, right?  So for example, if the document is an image of their drivers license, and they have access to the URL, they could download the image and email it, or they could share the url - either way, they just sent their drivers license out.

Comment: @Jay Actually it's not clear to me if they want the end user to be able to download their file from storage from some HTTPS endpoint (not necessarily the public download URL), or if the app can use the Storage SDK to perform the download.  It makes a big difference, as it might be a requirement to give the browser a URL it understands rather than a gs:// type URL.

Comment: @Jay, I see your point. The concern is that links to these files will probably end up being transferred via email, and I'm looking for a way to make it less easy to accidentally disclose access to private files. It would be much more intention to download and attach an image or PDF to an email than to forward an email that has a link you didn't realize was there.

Comment: The app will not use the files internally, but rather will initiate a download when clicking a button. I was hoping the download could rely on a 1-time use link so it could only be downloaded by clicking the button within a logged-in session. What the user chooses to do with the file after that (attach it to an email, forward it, etc) becomes an obvious and intentional action.